# Why Wont My Cat Facts Request Give Me The Right Information

Tags: python, api

Im trying to get information from this Cat Facts API in which I receive two cat facts in the son format. Here is my code and the link is where the website is from.

```
import requests


cats = requests.get("https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/GET /facts/random?animal_type=cat&amount=2")
print(cats.text)
cats_json = cats.json()
print(cats_json)
```

Link: https://alexwohlbruck.github.io/cat-facts/docs/endpoints/facts.html

When I run the code it tells me that     "raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" Could some one please assist me in fixing this. What I want the code to return is something like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "591f9894d369931519ce358f",
        "__v": 0,
        "text": "A female cat will be pregnant for approximately 9 weeks - between 62 and 65 days from conception to delivery.",
        "updatedAt": "2018-01-04T01:10:54.673Z",
        "deleted": false,
        "source": "api",
        "sentCount": 5
    },
    {
        "_id": "591f9854c5cbe314f7a7ad34",
        "__v": 0,
        "text": "It has been scientifically proven that stroking a cat can lower one's blood pressure.",
        "updatedAt": "2018-01-04T01:10:54.673Z",
        "deleted": false,
        "source": "api",
        "sentCount": 3
    }
]
```

Comment: What does `print(cats.text)` output?

Comment: The site doesn't seem to be very responsive, are you sure that you don't get an empty response after some timeout?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille it seems to be serving 503s at the moment, which may explain why the response is undecodeable ...

Comment: The error message is typical for an empty response. Check that the request worked before plunging ahead. Look at `requests.raise_for_status()`

Comment: Why do you have `GET` in the middle of the URL? That's part of HTTP syntax, it shouldn't be in the URL itself.